# How to benchmark gems loading time in rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in any rails app there is a `Gemfile` that bundle uses to satisfy this application required gems, when adding too many gems -which is a bad thing- you application will get slower while running your any rails/rake command.
so if you want to get rid of some slow gems you may want to know first what are the most slow gems to remove what you really don't need in you app.

so how to spot the slow gems?,i thought that i may create some kind of monkey patch for bundler to display each gem and loading time/Memory usage table, this will help getting rid of some gems.

Note: i know there is some solutions for slowness like spork and so, but i need to get the app lighter first before using them.

Comment: Yep, [bumbler](https://github.com/nevir/Bumbler) was created for exactly this purpose.

Comment: yes Damien this is what i meant, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as Damien Roche mentioned the solution was to use [bumbler](https://github.com/nevir/Bumbler) gem

```
$ gem install bumbler
$ cd path/to/project
$ bumbler
```